# VBA and printing Excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba, printing

Good morning,
how can I intercept, in the "Workbook_BeforePrint" event, the printing choice made by the user (the whole folder, active sheets, current selection). I would, for example, to inhibit the printing of a specific sheet (eg: Sheet2) if the user has chosen to print the entire folder.
Thank you very much

Ivo

Comment: Can you post your code, what have you tried so far?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Goto the link and read the paragraph titled [Prevent Printing Of A Specific Worksheet](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/preventing-users-from-printing-excel-workbook-tabs-vba-disable-macro)

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate each worksheet in the loop and decide what to do.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Debug.Print ws.name 'Do we want to print this?
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I know this method. But my question is a bit different: can I know from VBA if the user has chosen to print the whole workbook, only the active folders or the current selection? There is a method for this (e.g: ThisWorkbook.SelectionType ? or something similar)?